# Is it reasonable to use "by so far"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it reasonable to say: "This is going to be the most amazing day by so far!" ? I mean the "by so far" part. English is not my first language, but I caught myself typing so and started wondering where did I get that from. It's just without the "by" I feel like something is missing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking if you didn't know, but as @John's answer makes clear, there's nothing to be gained by looking any deeper. So I'm voting to close as "general reference".

Comment: Don't agree with you, the answer actually is pretty interesting and might come in handy for someone else too.

Comment: As implied, my vote to close doesn't mean I don't think the question should never have been asked - and I certainly wouldn't vote to *delete* it. But to my mind John's answer says just about everything that needs to be said, so there's no point in leaving it open in hopes of a better one coming alone later.

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close a question simply because it's been answered, even if I thought the answer was "perfect" and could never be improved upon. But this one is a simple case of conflating two different "set phrases". Bear in mind the question itself has only attracted one upvote - I think that's because although the answer may be helpful to you personally, it's not something that a lot of other people see as interesting.

Comment: Oh please.. most of the questions dont even get 1 upvote.

Comment: Well, it's quite unusual to see a non-closed question with only 1 upvote, where the answer has 8 upvotes. I still don't see what's to be gained by inviting others to see if they can post a "better" answer - but obviously only one other person agreed with me, so I guess mine is a minority position here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You're conflating two idioms with *far*:

1. *By far* modifies comparatives and superlatives, and indicates that the degree to which they exceed other compared things is very, very great. *This is the best one by far.*
2. *So far* is a distance measurement meaning *as far as this*. It's often used with the **TIME is DISTANCE** metaphor theme to mean *up until now*. *This is the best one so far.*

Since this is a superlative expression, you can use *by far*; since it means *up until now*, you could also use *so far*. Either one works.

**But** you can't use them together. Pick one.

Answer (score 1):

*The most amazing day so far* means 'up to now'; *the most amazing day by far* means 'much the best'; your example is ambiguous. I wouldn't say it's ungrammatical (*by such a long way*, meaning the same, would be a weak phrase, but certainly not wrong), but it's not good.